# Test meteor packages with jasmine without using CLI

Tags: meteor, jasmine, automated-tests, velocity

I know i can test meteor packages using jasmine command line interface as is described [here](https://velocity.readme.io/docs/jasmine-testing-a-meteor-package). But to do that i need to spawn another instance of application on another port where the results are shown. However, while testing test on application level the results of this test are shown directly in application, i can view them by click the velocity icon in the top right corner of screen. I want the same behaviour to apply to testing packages - so i can view the results of these test directly in my app.

Why? My application is all divided into packages, so all the code is in packages. So my application test screen shows no test, and my packages test screen shows a lot of test - but in another window. I don't want it that way.

Comment: The command is shown on that page: run meteor with `VELOCITY_TEST_PACKAGES=1 meteor test-packages --driver-package velocity:html-reporter mypackagename` to test the mypackagename package. You can remove the package name to test all packages at once.

Comment: I understand, but it's still CLI. I want my result to be shown in app's test screen.

Comment: This uses the html-reporter which displays the results in-app, so I'm not sure what you mean. You may need to add the velocity:html-reporter package to your app for this to work.